# regex - add space before any character that is not a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried many things and am looking for a space to be added after any character that is not a letter. Currently I can replace all non letter characters with a space, but I want a space **before** the character is matched. At the moment I have:

```
var str = 'div#some_id.some_class';
str = str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ' ');
```

This provides me with the following,

```
div some_id some_class
```

however I am looking for the result to be `div #some_id .some_class`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is `föóbàr` to `f ö ób àr` (and things along this line) also the result of what you want? Or would you have a smaller subset of characters in mind which you specifically consider to be matches (like `.`, `#` etc)?

Comment: the answer below provides what I am looking for, but I am only looking for a smaller subset ie. ```.```, ```#```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
str = str.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9_])/g, ' $1') //Omit 0-9 if you you want a space before them too

//OUTPUT: div #some_id .some_class
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can use a **negative lookahead** for this:

```
str = str.replace(/(?!\w|$)/g, ' ')
//=> "div #some_id .some_class"
```

`(?!\w|$)` will match positions where next character is not alpha0numeral or end of line.

Comment: this is great. If I wished to  to just match ```.``` and ```#``` as there is a case where ```_``` is matched and a space is also provided, which I dont want. How would this need to be changed to do this?

Comment: Actually as I further inspected this is not the exact answer I was looking for but the one provided by Zee. Really appreciate your help with this

Comment: sure, if you read the question the output I am looking for is ```div #some_id .some_class```, again thanks very much for the help

Comment: Ah sorry I misread output you're getting as the output you expected. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use groups and substitution

```js
var str = 'div#some_id.some_class';
str = str.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9])/g, ' $1');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I know, he says in the question **after** but his results show **before**

Comment: apologies, I did mean before. Thanks

Comment: I Have tried your answer it works well, but when I add special charcters side by side like div#some_id.#some_class and it also not working for $ special charcter

Comment: @nagarajub, I tried div#some_id.#some_class, it is working. It inserts a space before each special character. Regarding $, that itself needs to be escaped

Comment: @AmmarCSE Sorry My mistake.. Did not observe correct... my log console font is very small....

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exact subset in mind, you'd probably be better of to specify just (but exactly) that (since Unicode has quite some characters you might not have even thought about.. think about things like unintended `föóbàr` to `f ö ób àr`, not even mentioning languages that don't really use `A-z`):

```js
var str = 'div#some_id.some_class';
str = str.replace( /[.#]/g    // add your exact subset to match on between the [ ]
                 , ' $&'      // $& inserts the matched substring (no capturing group needed)
                 );
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try at `\b` word boundaries, where a `\W` non word character is ahead:

`(?=\W)\b` and replace matched position with a space ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mE5eU9/1)).